# Postgresql, how to SELECT json object without duplicated rows

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to find out how to get JSON object results of selected rows, and not to show duplicated rows.

My current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (vp.id) jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('affiliate',a.*)) as affiliates, jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('vendor',vp.*)) as vendors FROM
affiliates a
INNER JOIN related_affiliates ra ON a.id = ra.affiliate_id
INNER JOIN related_vendors rv ON ra.product_id = rv.product_id
INNER JOIN vendor_partners vp ON rv.vendor_partner_id = vp.id
WHERE ra.product_id = 79 AND a.is_active = true
GROUP BY vp.id
```

The results that I receive from this is:

```
[
affiliates: {
affiliate: affiliate1
affiliate: affiliate2
},
vendors: {
vendor: vendor1,
vendor: vendor1,
}
```

As you can see in the second record, vendor is still vendor1 because there are no more results, so I'd like to also know if there's a way to remove duplicates.

 Thanks.

Comment: Your output does not look consistent with the query. There should be one array of affiliates, and another array of vendors - which is not what you are showing here.

Answer (score 5):

First point : the result you display here above doesn't conform the json type : the keys are not double-quoted, the string values are not double-quoted, having dupplicated keys in the same json object ('{"affiliate": "affiliate1", "affiliate": "affiliate2"}' :: json) is not be accepted with the jsonb type (but it is with the json type).

Second point : you can try to add the `DISTINCT` key word directly in the jsonb_agg function :

> ```
> jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('vendor',vp.*))
> ```

and remove the `DISTINCT ON (vp.id)` clause.

You can also add an ORDER BY clause directly in any aggregate function. For more information, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES).

Answer (score 0):

You could aggregate first, then join on the results of the aggregates:

```
SELECT a.affiliates, v.vendors 
FROM (
  select af.id, jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('affiliate',af.*)) as affiliates
  from affiliates af
  group by af.id
) a  
  JOIN related_affiliates ra ON a.id = ra.affiliate_id
  JOIN related_vendors rv ON ra.product_id = rv.product_id
  JOIN (
    select vp.id, jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('vendor',vp.*)) as vendors
    from vendor_partners vp
    group by vp.id
  ) v ON rv.vendor_partner_id = v.id
WHERE ra.product_id = 79 
 AND a.is_active = true
```